# Hansontable set default value to dropdown when pasted data

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I need to copy paste from excel to my web application. I used Handsontable plugin and it works absolutely fine, there is only 1 place I am not able to move forward is, I have a default dropdown for every row that is pasted, The data too loads fine in the dropdown I want to select a **default value** in **dropdown** for all the data pasted.

Source Code:

```
var dataObject = [
{
    id: '',
    currencyCode: '',
    currency: '',
    test: 'Select one'
}
];

var hotElement = document.querySelector('#hot');
var hotElementContainer = hotElement.parentNode;
var hotSettings = {
data: dataObject,
columns: [
{
    data: 'id',
    type: 'numeric'
},
{
    data: 'currencyCode',
    type: 'text'
},
{
    data: 'currency',
    type: 'text'
},
{
    data:'test',
    type: 'dropdown',
    source: ['Select one', 'Uploaded', 'Not Available', 'Not Applicable'],
    width: 100
}
],
stretchH: 'all',
width: 500,
autoWrapRow: true,
height: 487,
maxRows: 2050,
rowHeaders: true,
colHeaders: [
'Loan Number',
'Document',
'Document Category',
'Resolution'
],
manualRowResize: true,
manualColumnResize: true,
manualRowMove: true,
manualColumnMove: true,
contextMenu: true,
filters: true,
dropdownMenu: true
};

var hot = new Handsontable(hotElement, hotSettings);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hot"></div>
```